# Remainder of product of n elements

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

I have for the first time in my life tried to write down a conjecture which I undoubtedly assume has a nice and understandable proof, but I kind of wanted to see if it’s true by myself or if I’m wrong. Please help me out.

“Given a set $X$ with elements $x$ in it, represented in terms of remainders$\mod n$ as such: $x = q\cdot n + b$; the following congruence holds:
The product of all the elements$\mod n$ is congruent to the product of all the remainders $b\mod n$”

This might seem both intuitive and childishly easy to many of you, but I’d love some guidance with a rigorous proof.

Thank you!

Comment: If you think it’s true, why? Have you worked out any examples? You will get more appreciation of a question if you tell us what you’ve thought about. Otherwise, it sounds a lot like you’re asking for the answer to a homework problem.

Comment: My suggestion is start with two numbers, $x_1=q_1n + r_1$ and $x_2=q_2n+r_2$ and play around with it  (do the product, factorize $n$ whenever possible, etc.) to check your conjecture.

Answer (score 0):

Prove it for two numbers, say:

$$\begin{cases}x=mn+a=a\pmod n\\{}\\y=ln+b=b\pmod n\end{cases}\;\;\implies xy=mln^2+(al+bm)n+ab=ab\pmod n$$

Now use a little induction...

This stuff is studied in basic algebra, either within number theory, or m,ore likely perhaps in group theory...